# How to delete websites I have browsed?

Tags: settings, internet-explorer, history

I have attempted to delete the history of web sites I visit by choosing Settings/Delete history. Although the "deleting browsing history" message appears on the phone screen, the website is not deleted. It appears the next time I open IE.

How can I remove these websites permanently?

Answer (score 2):

The recently browsed website will always appear when you reopen IE. You have to close the tab in IE and then it won't show up. Deleting the history from IE on gets rid of the list of websites under "Recent".